# Visual studio 2015, Web Form View / Designer - Error: class not registered looking for object with clsid

Tags: web, visual-studio-2015, designer

I've just installed VS 2015 Community on my PC (Win 10)

In the web form editor the Split tab is not active and Design freezes the window.

If I click - Menu / View / Designer  the following error occures: class not registered looking for object with clsid {A53914B4-1C62-4D60-8E8D-C7B67B4DFF87}

I tried to fix and reinstall the VS but the result is the same.

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it repairing VS 2015 from installer. You should try it.